# Database collations mismatch - TYPO3 Upgrade from 7.x to 10.x

Tags: mysql, database, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-10.x

I'm really stuck on some problems that occurred during my TYPO3 upgrade from 7 to 10.

The following error shows in the log and due to this, I can't do anything on the backend.

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE tags2, cache1 FROM cache_hash_tags AS tags1 JOIN cache_hash_tags AS tags2 ON tags1.identifier = tags2.identifier JOIN cache_hash AS cache1 ON tags1.identifier = cache1.identifier WHERE tags1.tag IN ('pageId_1','sys_template','sys_template_1')': Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' | Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException thrown in file /html/typo3/typo3_src-10.4.21/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php in line 110.

And I found this in DB there are different collations used and I'm thinking this would be the cause of the error.

[image: dbimage]

My question is, can we change the collations and charset of the entire database, tables, and table fields?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue of TYPO3. It is caused by the changed default settings of your database.

As you'll see [`ext_tables.sql`](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/core/ext_tables.sql) does not contain any information about which collation should be used. It's a choice of you/your sysadmin.

Back to your question. "can we change the collations and charset of the entire database, tables, and table fields?": it depends ;-)

Changing the collation of existing tables can be possible but might cause problems with the stored data.

- For tables storing temporary data (like the cache tables) truncating the tables and changing the collation should be harmless. (Or maybe faster: delete them and do a "Database compare")
- For tables storing content, you should check if changing the collation is compatible.

Comment: yes, as you said we did not mention the collations in "ext_tables.sql".Then what may be the best way to import the database from typo3 v7 (the old version uses the "utf8_general_ci") to typo3v10 (the new version which uses "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"). 
@Julian Hofmann

Answer (score 0):

You talk about a collation mismatch between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci. Both basically only differ in the default sorting of a query result. The data stored in the tables is identical.

Your screenshot lets me assume that you have access to phpMyAdmin. To change the collation of a table with phpMyAdmin, select the table and open the "Operations" tab. You will find a select field to choose the desired collation. Change it and save.